# Is it possible to use variables in MySQL schema definition?

Tags: mysql, schema

I need to do something like this:

```
use mydb;
SET @DBNAME = 'users';
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `key_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES @DBNAME.`users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

**REFERENCES @DBNAME.`users`** - is the part I'm interested in.

Is it possible to somehow parametrize DB name in schema definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use variables for object names. What you can do is compose the statement string dynamically and `PREPARE` then `EXECUTE` it.

```
SET @DBNAME = 'users';
SET @STMT = CONCAT(
'CREATE TABLE `some_table` (',
'  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,',
'  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,',
'  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),',
'  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,',
'  CONSTRAINT `key_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES ', @DBNAME, '.`users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION'
);
PREPARE s1 FROM @STMT;
EXECUTE s1;
```

Comment: But that must be inside a Stored Procedure, not outside.